# how to perform same key press event in safari?

Tags: python, selenium, safari, safaridriver

```
selenium 3.0.2 
safari 10 (using built in safari driver) 
python 2.7.10 
OSX 10.11.16(El Capitan)
```

> How to perform key press event (Right/Left/Up/Down) more than once using
>   send_keys(Keys.Right)   (i.e trying to move focus with repetitive key press actions using key press)

Example: Unable to enter right key three times using code bellow.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
```

There is no error present, just that the second key press event is not actioned. However if another direction key is sent in the sequence then that works, but once a key direction is used then the same direction key doesn't work in the same safari driver session.

Example: if the following is executed in a sequence in a single safari driver session, then:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT) #Works  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT) #Doesn't Work  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.LEFT) #Works  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.LEFT) #Doesn't Work
```

Example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT) #Works  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.LEFT) #Works  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT) #Doesn't Work  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.UP) #Works  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.LEFT) #Doesn't Works
```

Expected Results: Focus should move in same directions as many times as the send keys methods are called.
Bellow key press event should move the selection in safari10 browser to three selections in the right and two selection down and two selection to left.

Example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.DOWN)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.DOWN)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.LEFT)  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.LEFT)
```

Actual Results:
focus will move right only once. second time key press even wont move the focus if it is in same direction.

Note: The above example and steps works fine with the Firefox.

Comment: Have you seen auto.py or robots?

Comment: haven't tried that, Using python UnitTest framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch mechanize library that emulate a browser and there is many action that you can do.
Anyway try to put a delay between two command ,because its possible that the browser can't read a immediately response like you do till now

Comment: mmm ,I think it is better if you try to learn better the safari documentation because I can suppose that safari block this sequential access but I'm not sure ,anyway understand better safari  that can still be a good idea

Comment: Thanks for trying duca. I will try and dig out safari selenium documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use actionChains:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChain(element)
actions.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)  # actions are appened in a sort of waiting list
actions.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
actions.perform()  # then they are executed
```

Comment: Thanks, but already tried this. Same behaviour, it doesn't allow more than one key stroke in the same direction

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `send_keys` events are being treated as `key_down` events which have no effect when applied multiple times without a `key_up` being triggered in between. This sounds like a bug in the Safari driver and you might want to report it. In the meantime, you can try adding a useless key press in between the duplicate `send_keys` actions; something that won't have any effect on the page. But this is more of a hack than a fix.

For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys("y") # pick a key that doesn't do anything
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I've tried this and I am seeing the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This was a driver bug, and it's no longer present in macOS High Sierra/Safari 11. The fixes in WebKit are tracked in the following bugs:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=172299
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169733